# From XML to JSON on a Nodejs service

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to know how can I convert XML to JSON in this case, this is the json I am receiving

this is from an object named `dataset` which you will see below in a function

```
[{ BET: 57635034,
      CUSTOMER: 181645,
      SPORT: 'NFL',
      'XX_FILL OPEN': '<element><element_type>WAGER_ACTION_BUTTON</element_type><element_call>fillOpen(57635034)</element_call><element_content/></element>',
      XX_VIEW: '<element><element_type>BASIC_DROPDOWN</element_type><element_call>callThisFunction()</element_call><element_content><li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li><li>4</li></element_content></element>',
      XX_CANCEL: '<element><element_type>BASIC_CHECKBOX</element_type><element_call/><element_content>1</element_content></element>' 
}...]...
```

as you see there are some XML properties, all I need is take those XML elements and send them as json.

like this

```
[{ BET: 57635034,
      CUSTOMER: 181645,
      SPORT: 'NFL',
      'XX_FILL OPEN': {json: json},
      XX_VIEW: {json: json},
      XX_CANCEL: {json: json} 
}...]...
```

This is the function in the Nodejs service I am using

```
  pendingBetsForCustomer: function(params) {
    return new Promise(function(fullfill, reject) {
      var connection = new sql.Connection(sails.config.connections.theCap, function(err) {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        }
        var request = connection.request();
        request.execute('[SOME_SP].[CALL_SP]', function(err, dataset) {
          if (err) {
            reject(err);
          }

          //this log returns the data I pasted above
          console.log(dataset);

          if (request.parameters.param_GRID_REPORT_ID.value !== null) {
            _.forEach(dataset, function(report) {
              fullfill(report);
            });
          }
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

I was doing this but I got undefined:

```
var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;

parseString(dataset, function(err, res{console.log(res)});
```

so, what can I do to convert those XML parts into json?

Answer (score 1):

Basically your code is correct

```
var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;

parseString(dataset, function(err, res{console.log(res)});
```

But you don't have to pass the `dataset`variable, which I guess is the following

```
[{ BET: 57635034,
  CUSTOMER: 181645,
  SPORT: 'NFL',
  'XX_FILL OPEN': '<element><element_type>WAGER_ACTION_BUTTON</element_type><element_call>fillOpen(57635034)</element_call><element_content/></element>',
  XX_VIEW: '<element><element_type>BASIC_DROPDOWN</element_type><element_call>callThisFunction()</element_call><element_content><li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li><li>4</li></element_content></element>',
  XX_CANCEL: '<element><element_type>BASIC_CHECKBOX</element_type><element_call/><element_content>1</element_content></element>' 
}...]...
```

What you have to do, pretending that `dataset` is the above array you have to convert one field at the time.

```
var xml = dataset[0].XX_VIEW;

var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;

parseString(xml, function(err, res{console.log(res)});
```

You can as well loop through the dataset, like I see you do in `_.forEach(dataset, function(report) {`

In this case, you can use the report variable to access `XX_VIEW`, so you have to to do something like this `parseString(report.XX_VIEW, function....)`